# . FireDAC SQLite typecast with AS "fld::type" in nested queries/functions. How to?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, firedac

My fundamental question:

**How to resolve the problem with following SQL statement, with typecast:**

```
SELECT myDate FROM ( select datum AS [myDate::DATE] from [demo] )
```

*this is functional but problematic in nested queries/functions:*

```
SELECT [myDate::DATE] FROM ( select datum AS [myDate::DATE] from [demo] )
```

The searched solution would be **reflecting only the name in the result**, 
*but not the whole expression, including the typecast.*

I use **Delphi** and i have **FireDAC's source code**.

*Therefore it can also be a programmatical solution.*

### **Background of the problem and simple example:**

In the case FireDAC with SQLite,
only one real solution for typecasting is
**"AS alias::< T >"** syntax.

See the fourth's row of **SQL commands** below.

In my example the DATE type is used. If not typecasted, field will return data as Double, resp. REAL. But in the sense of how the function was declared this should be type DATE. Correct type is very important for use in other / nested / SQL commands or other functions.

**But it's not just about using dates..**
A similar problem occurs with the text as the result of the function. When it is defined as Varchar (20). The result of type Memo or Text(32767) is returned, rather than Text(20).

So we will need this:

```
SUBSTRING(..) AS myResult::Text(20)
```

Few **SQL commands** used as example:

```
DROP TABLE if exists [demo];
CREATE TABLE if not exists [demo] ( [id] Integer, [Datum] DateTime );
INSERT INTO [demo] ( [id], [Datum] ) VALUES ( 1, GETDATE() );
CREATE VIEW if not exists [myView] AS select [id], [datum] AS [myDate::DATE] from [demo];
```

Let's look at the prepared data:

*The second SQL of next three selects will fail.* 
**But that's the one we just need !!!**

This will run without problem

```
SELECT * FROM [myView];
```

My second SQL will fail with:   **[FireDAC].[Phys].[SQLite] ERROR: no such column: myDate**

```
SELECT [myDate] FROM [myView];
```

This will run without problem, but using it in nested selects will be a major disadvantage:

```
SELECT id, [myDate::DATE] FROM [myView];
```

On the contrary, in the **delphi source code**, this ***expected and correct*** name "**myDate**" was obtained as the **field name**.
Used test code:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text:= "select * FROM [myView]"
FDQuery1.Active := true;
sName := FDQuery1.Fields[1].FieldName     // its value is correct "myDate"
```

**For using with nested queries/functions**,
it is quite important that fields in queries returns only **short name** after **AS**, but **not a full expression**:   *name::typeCast*.

I know that special typecast ( .. AS [name::Type] ) is a FireDAC's specialty and benefit for SQLite.
It replaces certain limitations for this database engine. But for real use, I think that the remarks mentioned above have their meaning.

Note:
Fuction CAST as such has exactly the same problem as other functions in SQLite. Instead of the selected type, it returns only one of the basic types (Integer, Real, Text, Blob)

**But FireDAC offers DATETIME, CURRENCY, CHAR (Length) and many more types !**

It's just about making them real. And this my remark is about it.

Thanks in advance

Miroslav

Comment: FireDAC is data access library, not SQLite database engine. FireDAC only interprets the columns it receives from sqlite3.dll. Just use typecast in the right place: SELECT DATUM as [myDate::DATE] FROM (select datum from [demo])

Comment: I understand there is no better answer. I accept it as a solution.